# Enum of HashMap to sqlx type

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

Is it possible to convert an enum of hashmap to sqlx json using the enum variant name as the tag type just as with serde? E.g.

```rust
enum EnumEg {
    Variant1(HashMap<String, String>),
    Variant2
}

const BIND_LIMIT: usize = 65535;

// blah blah blah

let mut ha: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
ha.insert("a".to_string, "b".to_string());

let items = vec![EnumEg::Variant1(ha)];

// blah blah blah

let mut query_builder =
            QueryBuilder::new("INSERT INTO table (item)");
query_builder.push_values(
    items.take(PG_BIND_LIMIT / 2),
        |mut b, item| {
            b.push_bind(item);
        },
    )
);
// blah blah blah
```

Comment: Looking around a little bit, I came across the [`sqlx::types::Json`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/types/struct.Json.html) documentation. This should allow you to read and write a JSON field from database. That assumes your column is set to some sort of JSON type in the database. If not, then you can simply use the `serde_json::to_string` and `serde_json::from_str` functions to serialize/deserialize manually.

Comment: Thanks for the insight `sqlx::types::Json` seems to work just fine.